# A simple comparison in utf8, wrong result?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

this code prints "no" , but it should print "ok" and utf8 encodes of two are different

```
$a="کیهان";
$b="كيهان";
echo utf8_encode($a)."==".utf8_encode($b)."<br>";
if(utf8_encode($a)==utf8_encode($b))
    echo "ok";
else
    echo "no";
```

and the result :

```
Ú©ÛÙØ§Ù==ÙÙÙØ§Ù
no
```

what's that © ?

edit : $a is copied and $b is typed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your unicode strings are different to begin with... shown here with spaces to hilight the point:

```
$a="ک ی ه ن";
$b="ك ي ه ن";
```

---

**EDIT:** *for curiosity's sake...*

[image: screen shot of text in sublime editor]

Seems that they display identically in the tab at the top of the file, which must have font features which combine characters together, but displays differently in the body of code, where it is actually displayed back to front.

Comment: How did you see that?  It was my first thought as well, but in my browser at least the strings look visually identical.

Comment: my flavor of vi, which doesn't do right-to-left languages, show this very clearly.

Comment: I pasted it into sublime edit 2, where it looks slightly different

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

*Billy's completely right (+1) about why the strings are not equal.  This answer may explain why you see garbage text after the conversion.*

I'm guessing that your original encoding is not ISO-8859-1.

See the first comment in [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php).

> Please note that utf8_encode only converts a string encoded in
>   ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. A more appropriate name for it would be
>   "iso88591_to_utf8". If your text is not encoded in  ISO-8859-1, you do
>   not need this function. If your text is already in UTF-8, you do not
>   need this function. **In fact, applying this function to text that is
>   not encoded in ISO-8859-1 will most likely simply garble that text.**

You may want [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) instead.